# Разница между ССП и СПП.

Tags: пунктуация

Из комментариев :

Я буду рад, если оппозиция победит и Украина войдет в Евросоюз. - СПП.Запятая перед "и" не ставится.

Мамочка подует,и всё пройдет. - ССП. Запятая перед "и" ставится.

А в чем разница между предложениями?
Оппозиция победит,а следовательно Украина войдет.
Мамочка подует,а следовательно все пройдет.

Объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я буду рад, если оппозиция победит и Украина войдет в Евросоюз. - СПП.Запятая перед "и" не ставится.

Вы неправильно трактуете. Это СПП, но в нем **два** подчиненных: "оппозиция победит" и "Украина войдет в Евросоюз" при гланом "Я буду рад"". Поскольку подчиненные присоединены с помощью одного союза "если", то запятая перед соединяющим И не ставится.

Второе предложение состоит двух простых, соединенных союзом И. тут без запятой - никак. Разве что заменить её на тире.

Comment: Теперь понял.Спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

Первое предложение - сложноподчиненное с однородными придаточными (зависят от одного главного, отвечают на один вопрос, соединяются сочинительным союзом И). Между однородными придаточными знаки расставляются так же, как при однородных членах: один союз И - запятая не ставится, союз повторяющийся (соответственно придаточных не два, а больше)  - запятая ставится между однородными придаточными. У вас два однородных придаточных - запятая не нужна. От количества подчинительных союзов это вряд ли зависит. При однородных придаточных второй подчинительный союз может опускаться,а может и нет (Я буду рад, если оппозиция победит и если Украина войдет в Евросоюз).

Второе предложение сложносочиненное, запятая нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Попробую объяснить смысл такого решения. В первом случае (в СПП) мы соединяем с помощью союэа И два придаточных предложения в единое целое, чтобы отнести их к одному главному. Во втором случае (в ССП) перед нами самостоятельные предложения, союз И выражает временную последовательность событий. Таким образом, разная смысловая нагрузка союзов обозначена разной пунктуацией. Кстати, интонация предложений также разная: в первом случае придаточные составляют одну интонационную фразу,  а во втором они относятся к разным фразам, между которыми обозначается небольшая пауза.

Answer (score 0):

> [Я буду рад], (если оппозиция победит) и (Украина войдет в Евросоюз). - СПП.Запятая перед "и" не ставится,т.к. здесь принцип однородности. А между однородными членами с одиночным союзом И запятая не ставится.